# Toyota Camry 2003 drive seat won't move forward

Tags: toyota, power, camry, seat

We have a 2003 Toyota Camry.  Its driver seat power track won't move forward as it turns to the right after about 1/4 inch movement and cannot go forward.  However, it does go backwards all the way.  I took it to a Toyota dealer and after spending $100, he told me that I need a new Power tracking system which Toyota does not carry.  It will cost about $1,500.

However, the motor works and there is movement, so something must be wrong in the track, perhaps a loose track.  Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: Is there a way you can get underneath the seat and snap a couple of photo's of what you are describing?    particularly the piece that you describe turning to the right, before and after.  TY

Comment: You don't need to buy it new if you decide to replace the unit. Go to a junkyard and buy one. Much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you dropped coins on the floor and one of them got caught in the track.  Or maybe it's some other foreign object.  There should be 4 bolts holding your seat in place.  Remove the bolts, disconnect the connection switches underneath the seat and place the seat on top of the rear seats.  I've never tried what I'm about to tell you now but I myself would consider linking the seat switch with the connector on the seat floor by using 2 long wires.  one for the positive side of the switch and one for the negative side-- so that you might be able to get power to your track for testing purposes while the seat is NOT in it's position.  perhaps you'll be able to see the movement and locate the blockage much easier without the seat in the way.